817 optocoupler input terminal voltage and current
I analyzed 817 optocoupler in dozen brands of dial-up modems,caller id devices, private branch exchanges, i found most of them use 5v and some other use 3.3v for input terminals of 817 optocoupler. they limited the current (for example using resistor) but they did not reduce voltage.
but we see max forward voltage is 1.4v(20ma) in 817 datasheet (no relation noticed between current and voltage more than 1.4V 20ma)

817 datasheet source
I'm really confused what is happening for optocoupler in this industrial devices because they work grate but we see something else in datasheet.
Any analysis would be really appreciated.

You have to measure the voltage across Led (after series resistor). Then you should see 1.1-1.2V.

they limited the current (for example using resistor) but they did not reduce voltage - what does it mean? Optocoupler is basically an LED on the control side. You take your voltage (say 3.3V), subtract the typical forward voltage (3.3-1.4 = 1.9V) and chose a resistor such that it will produce the nominal current ( 20mA * R = 1.9V ). That is, if you want to work in the rated  range, you choose R such that R=(Vcc - Vf)/If

The voltage across a lit LED is determined by the chemistry of the LED and its colour, and only varies slightly with varying current.
The series curent-limiting resistor that we use with an LED will drop the voltage - a voltage is developed across a resistor dependent on the resistor value and current - see Ohm's Law.
If you want 10 mA current through the 817's input LED, and have a 3.3 volts supply, you will want about 2 volts across the resistor to leave 1.3 volts for the LED, so you will require a 200 Ohm resistor.  For a 5 volt supply, you want 3.7 volts across the resistor, and want a 370 Ohm resistor.
Note that LEDs, including the one in your 817, will emit light over a wide range of currents, so the resistor value isn't too critical.

The resistor will drop the voltage.
For example, 3.3V supply and 1.2V drop over LED at 20mA.
So there will be 2.1V left over the resistor, especially a 105 ohm resistor will drop exactly 2.1V at exactly 20mA current.

Being a diode with forward voltage 1.4V, the opto-coupler's LED would begin to conduct heavily as the voltage across it exceeds 1.4V. Applying a 5V potential difference directly across the LED would cause it to conduct so much current that it would be damaged.
The resistor is necessary to limit that current, since we still require to apply a 5V potential difference; that's the input signal's amplitude after all. Usually we start by choosing an amount of current we would like to have flow through the LED, and we calculate the resistance necessary to achieve that.
Let's say we want 10mA of LED current. We know that the LED will develop 1.4V (or close to that), and the remaining \$5.0V - 1.4V = 3.6V\$ will exist across the resistor, by KVL. The circuit and its state would look like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
With 3.6V across it, the required resistance can be calculated using Ohm,'s law:
$$ R_1 = \frac{V_{R1}}{I} = \frac{3.6V}{10mA} = 360\Omega $$
Therefore, when 10mA of current is flowing through R1 and D1, D1 develops its "natural" 1.4V, and R1 "consumes" the rest, 3.6V out of the 5V total. You might think of the resistor as providing some flexibilty to the diode, so that the diode gets to develop whatever voltage it "wants", and the resistor takes up the rest. In this way it's safe to apply 5V without destroying the diode.
